# A pointer to array of forward declared structures in C

Tags: c, gcc

I have a question about forward declarations in C.

***Code***

```
typedef struct yhash_s t_yhash;// forward declaration
struct yhash_s {
    size_t  size_h; 
    t_yhash (*yhash)[];// pointer to array of structures
};
```

Once the code is compiled with gcc, it complains:

*error: array type has incomplete element type ‘t_yhash’ {aka ‘struct yhash_s’}*

I do understand that `t_yhash` is not know (yet) and size of array can't be computed, but I am asking about pointer to an array of unknown yet size, which should be perfectly resolvable IMHO.

How do I fix that forward declaration and struct itself?

Comment: it's your parentheses that are causing the problem. You actually mean `t_yhash **yhash;`

Comment: If you have an array of something, you need to know the size of each element of the array. You can't have an array of structures of unknown size, and you can't declare a pointer to it, because you don't know the size of what it points to.

Comment: @KamilCuk You actually can https://ideone.com/3FKCrJ.

Comment: @EugeneSh. your example uses int as a the return type of the array of functions so it works.  But is not OP's intent, also `int` has a known type, so not applicable even if that *was* OPs intent.

Comment: @AhmedMasud My reply is strictly to KamilCuks comment (now removed..).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ah! :-)

Comment: True, @M.M, I just cut the fragment inaccurately form a bigger chunk of code to avoid cluttering, sorry.

Comment: I suppose that you could have an array of pointers which would be more common, and entirely possible.

Comment: As programming puzzles go, this is similar to declaring a function that can return a pointer to itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble is that array declarators may not have an incomplete type as the element type (C11 6.7.6.2/1). And `t_yash` (i.e. `struct yhash_s`) is not complete until the closing brace of the struct definition.

This rule is also responsible for another piece of trivia; it's legal to have (before the struct definition is complete):

```
void func( t_yhash *a );
```

but not legal to have:

```
void func( t_yhash a[] );
```

even though the adjustment rule would work just fine if not for the incomplete element type rule.

Probably the language design could be improved slightly by refining this rule to allow some cases like the function prototype, but it clearly wasn't something that arose with the language design committee.

But even without this rule, your use case might have another problem; the size of the pointer might not be known. It would be legal (although unlikely in practice) for "pointer to array of struct X" to have a different size than "pointer to array of struct Y". There is a rule that all pointers to struct must have the same size, but no such rule for pointers to array.

Comment: Is a pointer to incomplete type is an incomplete type? (not saying it is relevant here though)

Comment: C 2018 6.2.5 1 says “At various points within a translation unit an object type may be incomplete (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or complete (having sufficient information).” So, if you know how big it is, it seems to be complete.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't think so -- otherwise `void f (struct x *p) {}` would be an error (C11 6.7.6.3/4). But it is an interesting question

Comment: It is a complete type. Especially for struct pointers they should have same representations.

Comment: @M.M: For `struct x *p`, we know how big `p` is because all structure pointers have the same size. For `int (*p)[]`, an implementation could use different sizes of pointers for different arrays, so we might not know how big `p` is.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It's a constraint violation to have a struct with incomplete members (other than flexible array member), but compilers accept `struct S { int (*p)[]; int x; };` . Compiler bug, unspecified, or standard defect?  In any case this could be a separate question rather than a comment chain :)

Comment: @M.M: Okay, [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724711/can-a-pointer-to-an-incomplete-type-be-incomplete).

Answer (score 1):

In reply to this part of your post:

> How do I fix that forward declaration and struct itself?

You can use `void *` to stash your array, and then convert it back later.

```
typedef struct yhash_s t_yhash;
struct yhash_s {
               size_t  size_h;
               void *yhash;
               };

static inline t_yhash (*yhash(t_yhash y))[] {
    return y.yhash;
}
```

If the function syntax is too obtuse:

```
typedef t_yhash t_yhash_array[];

static inline t_yhash_array *yhash(t_yhash y) {
    return y.yhash;
}
```

For example:

```
t_yhash x[10];
t_yhash y = { 10, &x };
assert(yhash(y) == &x);
```

Comment: Thanks @jxh, that is a crazy one - it took me 5 mins just to read your code, LOL! :)

Comment: Ok, I gave the equivalent function with a typedef to illustrate what it means.