# Can a pointer to an incomplete type be incomplete?

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer, incomplete-type

Can `int (*)[]` be an incomplete type?

C 2018 6.2.5 1 says:

> At various points within a translation unit an object type may be *incomplete* (lacking sufficient information to determine the size of objects of that type) or *complete* (having sufficient information).

Thus it seems that if the size of a type is known, the type is complete. 6.2.6.1 28 specifies that certain types of pointers must have the same sizes (pointers to `void` and characters, pointers to compatible types, pointers to structures, and pointers to unions), but pointers to other types may vary.

In a C implementation where all pointers, or all pointers to arrays of `int`, have the same size, then the size of `int (*)[]` is known, so it would be complete. In an implementation that, say, uses different pointers for large arrays, the size would not be known, so it is incomplete.

As [M.M points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724078/a-pointer-to-array-of-forward-declared-structures-in-c/59724372?noredirect=1#comment105599413_59724372), a structure must not contain a member with incomplete type, except a final flexible array member, per a constraint in 6.7.2.1 3. This suggests that an implementation with one size of pointers must accept `struct { int (*p)[]; }` while an implementation that has different sizes for such arrays must diagnose a constraint violation. (This in turn means such a declaration is not part of strictly conforming C.)

Comment: 6.2.5(p22) help? (or does it add more confusion allowing the incomplete type to be completed by later declaration?)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin In 6.2.5/20 it's even said that pointers are always complete types

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: How would that be relevant? The question is “Is there an X that is not a Y?”, not “Is there an X that is a Y?”

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The fact that `void *` is complete shows that a pointer to an incomplete type can be complete. It does not show whether or not a pointer to an incomplete type can be incomplete. If one asked “Can a mammal be an elephant?”, showing that “A lion is a mammal” would not provide that a mammal cannot be an elephant. The question asks whether the set X of pointers to incomplete type may contain an element that is incomplete. Showing that the set X of pointers to incomplete type contains an element that is complete is irrelevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oops. I've misread the title as "Can a pointer to an incomplete type be **complete**?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An array of unknown size is incomplete:

> An array type of unknown size is an incomplete type. It is completed, for an identifier of that type, by specifying the size in a later declaration (with internal or external linkage).

The type `int (*)[]` however is not incomplete: It's a pointer of an array of `int` of unknown size.
And a pointer has a well known size:

```
printf ("Size %d\n", sizeof(int (*)[]));
```

> 6.2.5/23: A type has known constant size if the type is not incomplete and is not a variable length array type.

Furthermore you can even dereference it, thanks to the array semantics:

```
typedef int (*T)[];
...
int a[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) a[i]=i;
T p=a;
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) printf ("%d ",(*p)[i]);
printf ("\n");
```

#### Edit

In addition, a pointer is always a complete type.  It's written black on white in 6.2.5/20:

> A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type,
>   called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose
>   value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A
>   pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called
>   ‘‘pointer to T’’. The construction of a pointer type from a referenced
>   type is called ‘‘pointer type derivation’’. **A pointer type is a
>   complete object type.**

Comment: I think you have it boiled down and gcc agrees. [struct w/pointer to incomplete array](https://susepaste.org/21814463) is similar to the original question prompting the discussion.

Comment: Only the last paragraph is relevant. The example `printf` only shows that a pointer to an incomplete array is complete in the implementation it was executed in, as stated in the question—if it were not for 6.2.5 20, cited in the last paragraph, it might fail to compile. 6.2.5 23 is also not relevant; it tells us the size is known and constant if it is complete, and we already know that being complete means the size is known.

Comment: 6.2.5 20 is interesting. I speculate it was not intended to have this consequence, but it means that all pointers to complete types that have the same type when incomplete must have the same size. For example, all pointers to arrays of `int` must have the same size as each other, and all pointers to arrays of a certain `struct` must have the same size as each other, although perhaps not all pointers to arrays of different kinds of `struct` must have the same size as each other.

Comment: @EricPostpischil maybe the text "Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements." should be interpreted to say that `T(*)[]` must have the same size as `T(*)[5]`, since they are compatible types and we could add or remove qualifiers

Comment: Allowing compatible types to have different sizes would lead to a whole bunch of problems, it's probably a defect that the standard doesn't explicitly rule it out

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, only the last reference is definitive for the language layer and it took me some time to fond it back. The remainder is empirical evidence. The assumptions that pointers are pointers is an old one. A lot of code storing void (another incomplete type) pointers and casting back and forth would no longer work if it wasn’t the case.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Interestingly the discussion about working with pointers of different size seem of have taken place a long time ago in the times of [intel’s 8086 memory models](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model) at a time “Microsoft C” was still called “Lattice C”. It ended up in data pointers of homogeneous size in each model (except code and data and IMHO this is why there are nowadays still some constraints about casting function pointers)

Comment: @EricPostpischil correction to my first comment: indeed pointers can have different size depending on what they point to. Intel’ memory models allowed function pointers of different size than data pointers. So I did some archelogical work to find out that conversion between function pointers and void* was introduced in C99 (see this [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf). Reading the section about pointers it appears that void* must be large enough to hold them all, but ptr to different types can have different size.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As a consequence of all this, you can infer that pointers to arrays of a given type must be the same size regardless the size of the array. But theoretically a pointer to another incomplete type could have a different size.

Comment: Does it mean that a pointer type is _always_ a complete type? Extra: if yes, then any ideas why "6.7.6.1 Pointer declarators" does not say that?