# Misunderstanding of the structure С++

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof, incomplete-type

I apologize in advance for the question if it seems too "childish", but the question is:

Here is such a simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_struct
{
    struct fictitious_name fn_struct;
};



int main()
{
  
}
```

It is not compiled because the fictitious_name structure is not defined.

But then if I rewrite it thus:

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_struct
{
    struct fictitious_name* fn_struct;
};



int main()
{
  
}
```

Then everything is fine, the code is compiled, but the fictitious_name structure is still undefined.
Why does a pointer to a non - existent structure work ?

Comment: The C standard define an **incomplete** structure, in structures namespace, as soon as the compiler see the keyword `struct`. So the incomplete structure is defined, but you cannot use it because it is incomplete. On the other hand a **pointer to a structure** is always defined.

Comment: Please don't tag spam. C and C++ are two different languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This declaration

```
struct fictitious_name fn_struct;
```

introduces incomplete type `struct fictitious_name`. That is the size of an object of this type is unknown. As a result the compiler does not know how much memory to reserve for the object `fn_struct`.

In this declaration

```
struct fictitious_name* fn_struct;
```

there is also introduced incomplete type `struct fictitious_name`. But the size of the object `fn_struct` that has a pointer type is known. It is the size of a pointer. So the object `fn_struct` is of a complete type.

Pointers are always complete types.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types, p. #20)

> A pointer type is a complete object type.

Comment: *"Pointers are always complete types."* Is that really true? Some pointers can have different sizes than others.

Comment: @klutt From the C Standard  "A pointer type is a complete
object type."

Comment: @klutt: [Can a pointer to an incomplete type be incomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59724711/can-a-pointer-to-an-incomplete-type-be-incomplete)

Comment: @klutt - Even though pointers _can_ have different sizes, pointers to structs cannot (which follows from the fact that this code is valid :-).

Comment: @BoP Yes I know that. I was just wondering if it is possible to declare a pointer where it's not clear if it's a pointer to struct or function

Comment: @klutt - Function pointers is a different case again, as are pointers to members. :-)  This case is known to work, as it explicitly says `struct`. The others have a different syntax, so cannot be mixed up.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct my_struct
{
    struct fictitious_name fn_struct;
};
```

Here the contents of the inner struct are put in the outer struct. If definition is not known, size is not known and space can't be reserved.

---

```
struct my_struct
{
    struct fictitious_name* fn_struct;
};
```

Here pointer to inner struct is put into outer struct. Pointer to struct has known size, so it's no problem. If you try to access members of the inner struct or use `sizeof` on it (needed by `malloc` for example), then you need the definition. Until then, it's just a pointer and C does not need to know more.